# express session inSession: false

Tags: javascript, express

i keep getting

> inSession:false

[image]

when logging in, it should return true.

I'm using [express session](https://github.com/expressjs/session), along with postges, sequalize.

I console.log the state values and it renders the values, so its not undefined.

*A deeper error*

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api from localhost:3000 to
>   http://localhost:5000/ (ECONNREFUSED).

**routes/users.js** (handles the login logic)

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  User.findOne({
    where: {email: email}

  }).then( user => {

    if(!user){
      res.status(200).send({ incorrectEmail: true, inSession: false, msg: "Incorrect Email" })
    }else if(!user.validPassword(password)){
      res.status(200).send({ incorrectPassword: true, inSession: false, msg: "Incorrect Password" })
    }else{
      res.status(200).send({
        inSession: true, msg: "Logged in!", loggedEmail: user.email
      })
    }

  }).catch(err => next(err))
});
```

**signIn.js** That handles the Front End.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';
class signIn extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            email:"",
            password: "", 
            loggedEmail:"",
            loginError: "",    
            userLoggedIn: false,
            emailBlank: true,
            passwordBlank: true,
            emailInvalid: false,
            passwordInValid: false,
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });

    }


    handleSubmit = () => {

        this.setState({
            email: this.state.email, 
            password: this.state.password


        });

        if (!this.state.emailBlank && !this.state.passwordBlank){
            axios.post('/api/users/login',{
                email: this.state.email, 
                password: this.state.password


            }).then ( res => { 
                if (res.data.incorrectEmail|| res.data.incorrectPassword ){
                    this.setState({ loginError: res.data.msg})
                }
                this.setState({ userLoggedIn: res.data.inSession, loggedEmail: res.data.loggedEmail})

            }).catch( err => console.log(err))

        }else{
            this.setState({ emailInvalid: true, passwordInValid: true})

            console.log(  this.state.emailInvalid, this.state.passwordInValid)
        }

    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div style={ {padding: '20px 100px'}}>
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>      
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Email"
                    className=""
                    style={{width: 560}}
                    name="email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                />  
                <br></br>
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Password"
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    style={{width: 560}}
                    className=""
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                />  

                <br></br>

                <button type="submit"> Submit </button>

            </form>

            </div>

        );
    }





}

export default signIn;
```

**server** 
      ...

```
     app.use(session({
       key:'user_sid',
       secret: 'something',
       resave: false,
       saveUninitialized: false,
       cookie: {
       expires: 600000
      } 
     }))


    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if (req.cookies.user_sid && !req.session.user){
        res.clearCookie('user_sid');
      }
      next();
    })

    sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
      if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid){
        res.status(200).send({ inSession: true});
      } else {
        next();
      }
    }

    app.get('/api', sessionChecker, (req, res) => {
      res.status(200).send({ inSession: false });
    });

    app.use('/api/users', userRoute )
```

App.js (front app.js)

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      inSession: false,
      loggedEmail: "",
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkInSession()
  } 

  checkInSession = () => {
    axios.get('/api').then((res) => {
      this.setState({ inSession: res.data.inSession });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried logging from sessionChecker on the server? It looks like maybe there's something undefined in there.  Personally I would've just done the following:

```
// sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
//   if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid){
//     res.status(200).send({ inSession: true});
//  } else {
//    next();
//  }
// }

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({ inSession: (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid)});
  }
});
```

Comment: let me give this a shot

Comment: main concern is what exactly are you getting out of req.session.user or req.session.user_sid ... the answer is in what the server logs from those variables.

Comment: i copied it from another github source, im not really sure what it does exactly. All i know is that i need a way to let react/node know that a user signed in, and maintain the session until the user logs out. The code above got ride of the inSession:false. thank you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this middleware mutates the request object, so hopefully it does intervene. There's a chance someone could alter the request passed in to get the response they desire from the server. I would spend some time reading through the documentation for express-session to be safe. At the very least maybe logging the entire request in between each call to compare results. Or seeing what req.session.user looks like if you disable the middleware completely. User management is really annoying and I'm dealing with it now too. Good luck.